# Java - called paintComponent will be read but not implemented during runtime

Tags: java, swing, grid, jpanel

Essentially I am trying to add a circle to a JPanel grid matrix (This is where my main problem lies).
When running the code below, once the new OvalComponent class is called to add the circle to a the (1,1) position in the grid, the class is read, but the paint component function is just skipped.

```
package Exercises;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * Created by user on 4/1/2017.
 */
public class Mazes extends JPanel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Mazes maze = new Mazes();
}

public Mazes() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Boolean[][] maze = Exercise4.readMaze();
    int row = maze.length;

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Maze");
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, row));

    JPanel[][] grid = new JPanel[row][row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)        {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)                {
            grid[i][j] = new JPanel();
            grid[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            if ((i==1&&j==1) || (i==row-1 && j==row-1))
                grid[i][j].add(new OvalComponent());

            if (maze[i][j].equals(false)){
                grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);}
            else grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            f.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //f.add(new JButton("Reset"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
class OvalComponent extends JComponent {
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillOval(4, 4, 10, 10);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OvalComponent` has no definable size (defaults to `0x0`), so while the component is been added it's been added with a size of `0x0` and Swing is clever enough to know that it doesn't need to paint it.

Override the component's `getPreferredSize` method and return an appropriate size

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(18, 18);
}
```

as an example